# How do I pass a link that contains variables to a user_mailer model in a Rails 2.3.11 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass a link that contains variables to a mailer model. For such a simple email, I'd rather not use liquid.

controller:

```
...
@token = @user.authentication_token
link = "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/?token=<%= @token %>' >Click here</a>"
UserMailer.deliver_reminder(@user, @link)
```

model:

```
def reminder(user, link)
    recipients user.email
    from "service@mysite.com"
    subject "link"
    body "Go here: " + link
end
```

here's the way the link gets sent in the email:

```
<a href='https://www.mysite.com/?token=<%= @token %>' >Click here</a>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular string interpolation:

```rb
link = "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/?token=#{@token}'>Click here</a>"
```

Using string concatenation:

```rb
link = "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/?token=" + @token + "'>Click here</a>"
```

Comment: +1 for trying. thanks. but i get <a href='https://www.mysite.com/?token=oj6...' >Click here</a> in the email then.

Comment: Did you perhaps copy it down wrong? It's just that my solution doesn't contain a semicolon.

Comment: nope... tried both solutions exactly... triple checked syntax on each. I could eliminate the link syntax and use an ugly link that would result in an ugly link that looks like https://mysite.com/?token=oj6... instead of a nice clean "click here".

Comment: Maybe your `@token` variable, then? I tried it with a local variable: `token = 'ASDF' ; link = "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/?token=#{token}'>Click here</a>"`. Inspecting `link` yields `"<a href='http://www.mysite.com/?token=ASDF'>Click here</a>"`, as expected.

Comment: yep... well you wouldn't want "<a href..." in the email itself. I just want the "Click here" to show up in the email. Maybe it isn't possible.

Comment: Just make sure you're sending an HTML email, not plain text, and that the body of the email is escaped properly. You may need to use [`html_safe`](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) function.